# Querying MongoDB embedded documents, not arrays, in a tabular format

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I imported the below JSON into MongoDB (mongoimport --host localhost --db test --collection employees --type json --file Employees.json --jsonArray)

```
[ 
    {
        "Employee" : {
            "Basics" : {
                "Name" : "James Bond",
                "Age" : 42
            },
            "Addresses" : {
                "Address" : {
                    "City" : "London",
                    "Country" : "England"
                },
                "Address" : {
                    "City" : "Paris",
                    "Country" : "France"
                }
            },
            "Cars" : {
                "Car" : {
                    "Model" : "Aston Martin",
                    "Year" : 1977
                },
                "Car" : {
                    "Model" : "Audi",
                    "Year" : 2000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Employee" : {
            "Basics" : {
                ..
            },
            "Addresses" : {
                "Address" : {
                    ..
                },
                "Address" : {
                    ..
                }
            },
            "Cars" : {
                "Car" : {
                    ..
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

To get the results in a tabular format I used the below query but it fetches only Aston Martin and not Audi.

```
db.employees.aggregate( 
[
{$match: {'Employee.Basics.Name':{$eq:"James Bond"}}},
{$project: {carModel:'$Employee.Cars.Car.Model',_id:0}}
]);
```

1. Is there a way I can get both values? (In a tabular format with
   specific fields - not like
   db.getCollection('employees').find({'Employee.Basics.Name':{$eq:"James
   Bond"}});)
2. Looking at other examples, it looks like the JSON should have had Array of Cars and Addresses, is there a way I can update the documents in MongoDB to change them to Arrays now?

I'm new to MongoDB, (just 2 days old :)) so any pointers will be of great help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "tabular format"? Can you include an example output that you need in the question?

Comment: `> db.getCollection('employees').find({'Employee.Basics.Name':{$eq:"James Bond"}}, { _id: 0, 'Employee.Cars.Car.Model' : 1 });`         
**{ "Employee" : { "Cars" : { "Car" : { "Model" : "Aston Martin" } } } }**        
  
`> db.employees.aggregate([{$match: {'Employee.Basics.Name':{$eq:"James Bond"}}},{$project: {carModel:'$Employee.Cars.Car.Model',_id:0}}]);`        
**{ "carModel" : "Aston Martin" }**

Comment: The first result is hierarchical and the second one is tabular (sorry I may be using the wrong terms but I guess you can see the difference). **Moreover both the queries only return Aston Martin, but James bond also owns an Audi**

Comment: @joy_jedi What you seem to be missing about what people are asking you to clarify is things like your `"Car"` element actually shows 2 keys for `"Car"` under it. This is not valid for JSON or the BSON storage underpinning MongoDB. So you simply cannot have a document in that format. If you did try to import it, you would find there was only **"one"** `Car`, since that would be valid JSON, and the second "key" replaces the first. In brief, this is supposed to be an "Array" instead. So it's not clear which you are asking. How to query? Or how to "import". Seems the latter.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn for you reply. I later realized that my JSON which I was getting after doing a XML2JSON transformation is not a valid JSON because of the duplicate keys. Strangely, MongoDB allows me to import it but not query it. (Not sure if MongoDB is supposed to complain while importing but it didn't). Also, when I do a Mongoexport I do see both the Cars. I will post the Java code which I wrote to convert Cars and Addresses to array in the json before importing.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has ill-formed JSON like in my example, you can use the below Java code to fix it. (I got the JSON by using https://sourceforge.net/projects/xml2json-converter/).

```
private final Deque<Integer> arrayStack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
private final Deque<Integer> arrayElemStack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

String[] arrayElemNames = {"Employee","Address","Car"};
String[] arrayNames = {"Addresses","Cars"};

public void cleanJSON() throws IOException {

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputJsonFileName))) {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputJsonFileName))) {
            stream.map((str) -> formatRootElem(str)).map((str) -> formatArrayElems(str))
                    .map((str) -> formatArrays(str)).forEach((str) -> writeToOutput(writer, str));
        }
    }

}

private void writeToOutput(BufferedWriter writer, String str) {
    try {
        writer.write(str + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String formatRootElem(String str) {
    if (str.equals("{")) {
        return "[";
    } else if (str.equals("}")) {
        return "]";
    } else if ((str.contains("Employees") && str.contains("{")) || str.equals("  }")) {
        return "";
    }
    return str;
}

private String formatArrayElems(String str) {
    if (checkInArray(str, arrayElemNames)) {
        arrayElemStack.push(1);
        return "{" + str;
    }
    if (!arrayElemStack.isEmpty()) {
        if (str.contains("{")) {
            int count = arrayElemStack.pop();
            arrayElemStack.push(++count);
        } else if (str.contains("}")) {
            int count = arrayElemStack.pop();
            --count;
            if (count == 0) {
                str = str.replace("}", "}}");
            } else {
                arrayElemStack.push(count);
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

private String formatArrays(String str) {
    if (checkInArray(str, arrayNames)) {
        str = str.replace('{', '[');
        arrayStack.push(1);
    } else if (!arrayStack.isEmpty()) {
        if (str.contains("{")) {
            int count = arrayStack.pop();
            arrayStack.push(++count);
        } else if (str.contains("}")) {
            int count = arrayStack.pop();
            --count;
            if (count == 0) {
                str = str.replace('}', ']');
            } else {
                arrayStack.push(count);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    return str;
}

private boolean checkInArray(String str, String[] strArray) {
    for (String arrayElem : strArray) {
        if (str.contains(arrayElem) && str.contains(":")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```